# Re-using node modules in different projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there a good usage pattern for re-using node modules across several projects? I have several modules that I duplicate in a few different projects. I feel like this must be a solved problem; do people host private npm repositories? Setup symbolic links?

Comment: Install the module globally?

Comment: *I have several modules*  Are you low on disk space? What happens if one project needs a different version of the shared module?  I may be missing something, but this seems like a non-issue.

Comment: If IP isn't a problem, why not just publish to the npm registry? If IP is a problem, you can install from private git repositories using npm via SSH, e.g. `npm install --save git@github.com:org/privatething.git`. Just make sure your private key is set up correctly.

Comment: @Bergi that might work. But is it possible to install globally different versions of this module? Otherwise all projects have to be deployed at the same time.

Comment: @MattBrennan Most of these modules are Mongoose schemas, for example, not something I'm going to publish. Sounds like a private repo is the way to go. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: @TimCooper I think you're missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions :

#### If you mind disk space

*As in : no package should be installed twice*

- Install globally

  - Require root
  - Generally, global install is advised for binary packages, not for modules you're gonna require.
- Use npm link ([man page](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html))

  - doesn't require global install
  - Allow you to have just one version installed
  - Alllow you to modify locally this package

#### If you don't mind disk space

*As in : having same packages installed multiple times*

- Use git source

  - like git@github.com or any other git repo
  - You'll not have the ability to require a specific package version via package.json
  - you can use branches / tags to have multiple versions available
- Use a private npm repo as in [registry doc](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-registry.html)

  - not as complicated as it might seem
  - can be used as a cache if you want to speed up most packages download